Least error at $x=2$ for $\pi$ approximation
When I was playing around in desmos (again) due to this answer, I found this pattern: $$\pi \approx \frac{\pi}{\theta}\sin\theta(0 -(-1)\cos\theta) \\ \pi \approx \frac{\pi}{2\theta}\sin\theta(2 -0\cos\theta) \\ \pi \approx \frac{\pi}{3\theta}\sin\theta(4 -1\cos\theta) \\ \pi \approx \frac{\pi}{4\theta}\sin\theta(6 -2\cos\theta) \\ \dots \\ \pi \approx \frac{\pi}{(x+1)\theta}\sin\theta(2x -(x-1)\cos\theta)$$ This is easier to calculate by hand when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2^k}$. It is evident in the desmos graph that the third approximation from the top converges faster. My question is, why?
P.S. The first approximation is by extending this pattern backwards, the later approximations are by taking the area of a cubic, quartic, etc parabola in the above question.
Here's the graph.

$\approx$ is an ill-defined notation, so it is unclear how you can  can say anything about convergence.

I realized my mistake, I forgot this wasn't an infinite series

Are you approximating near $\theta=0$?

@SineoftheTime yes

Then it follows from the Taylor approximation of $\sin $ and $\cos $: $\sin \theta \sim \theta$ and $\cos \theta \sim 1$

yes, but why is the approximation better at $x = 2$?

What does "at $x=2$" mean? Do you mean "Why is the second approximation better than any of the others"?

@MishaLavrov at $x=2$ means that when you set $x=2$ in the general approximation under the other ones (fifth from the top)

@SineoftheTime I see why you are confused. At $x=2$, the approximation is $\pi \approx \frac{\pi}{3\theta}\sin\theta(4-\cos\theta)$.

To rearrange the expression slightly, you are approximating $\pi$ by $$\pi \cdot \left(\frac{2x}{x+1} \cdot \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} - \frac{x-1}{x+1}\cdot\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} \cdot \cos\theta\right).$$
If we write out the beginning of the Taylor series around $\theta = 0$, it is:

$1 - \frac{\theta^2}{6} + O(\theta^4)$ for $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$, and
$1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2} + O(\theta^4)$ for $\cos\theta$,
hence $(1 - \tfrac{\theta^2}{6} + O(\theta^4))(1 - \tfrac{\theta^2}{2} + O(\theta^4)) = 1 - \frac23 \theta^2 + O(\theta^4)$ for $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} \cdot \cos\theta$,

so the overall expression has a Taylor expansion of $$\pi\left(\frac{2x}{x+1}(1 - \tfrac{\theta^2}{6} + O(\theta^4)) - \frac{x-1}{x+1}(1 - \tfrac23 \theta^2 + O(\theta^4))\right)$$
which simplifies to $\pi + \frac{\pi(x-2)}{3x+3} \theta^2 + O(\theta^4)$.
The coefficient of $\theta^2$ simplifies to $0$ when $x=2$, making the expression converge to $\pi$ faster.

Is there any way to get better convergence than this?

Not from this sequence of approximations! Beyond that, the question is what other approximation might be geometrically motivated, to make it useful. (Algebraically, this is not a useful approximation for $\pi$, since it has a factor of $\pi$ inside it.)

Well, if not that, we do get a nice approximation of arctan for small x. $\arctan(x) \approx \frac{x(4\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - 1)}{3(x^2 + 1)}$, which can be used in Machin like formulae for pi. But, this approximation is not as good as the series for arctan.
